# Best method of showcasing UI interaction / animations for case studies or portfolios?

Tags: interface, video, animation, case-studies

I'm building a site full of case studies and I want the ability to show UI animations of how the user interacts with the interface. My app is a browser based app.

Some simple things I'd like to show:

- a user collapsing and expanding the left panel sections
- a user interacting with the file preview (zooming, dragging)

What method do people usually use for this? Do they just record with a screen recording app and then input the video into their site, or do they use a prototyping app and record from there? I am new to showcasing through video and animation so any thoughts would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting application for showing user interactions, depends on the number of interactions you wish to show at a time, and whether or not to use audio with demonstrations.

If the interactions are too small like just expanding and collapsing panels, you can create a GIF.
If interactions are too large a screen recording app is best suited for which there are many extensions available in chrome, mozilla firefox.
https://www.useloom.com/.
If you wish to create a customized video there are apps like CanvasFlip.
Also, you can find similar apps at https://medium.com/@CanvasFlip/prototyping-tools-to-record-your-mobile-app-web-prototypes-da7579a0d157